# Restructuring JSON file in JAVA

Tags: java, json, file

I am having the following sample from a JSON file:

```
[
{
  "0":
  {
    "File":"file1.java",
    "Class":"com.ETransitionActionType",
    "Method":"values",
    "Annotation":"Not Found"
  }
},
{
  "1":
  {
    "File":"file2.java",
    "Class":"com.ETransitionParams",
    "Method":"values",
    "Annotation":"Not Found"
  }
},
{
  "2":
  {
    "File":"file3.java",
    "Class":"com.phloc.commons.id.IHasID",
    "Method":"getID",
    "Annotation":"Not Found"
  }
},
{
  "4":
  {
    "File":"file3.java",
    "Class":"com.ExecuteTransitionActionHandler",
    "Method":"createBadRequestResponse",
    "Annotation":"Not Found"
  }
},
{
  "5":
  {
    "File":"file3.java",
    "Class":"com.ExecuteTransitionActionHandler",
    "Method":"extractParametersFromAction",
    "Annotation":"Not Found"
  }
}]
```

How can I restructure this file using java so that it looks like:

```
[{
    "file1.java": {
        "com.ETransitionActionType": {
            "values": {
                "Annotation": "Not Found"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "file2.java": {
        "com.ETransitionParams": {
            "values": {
                "Annotation": "Not Found"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "file3.java": {
        "com.phloc.commons.id.IHasID": {
            "getID": {
                "Annotation": "Not Found"
            }
        },
        "com.ExecuteTransitionActionHandler": {
            "getID": {
                "Annotation": "Not Found"
            },
            "extractParametersFromAction": {
                "Annotation": "Not Found"
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

i.e. Going through the JSON file, searching it, and wherever the "File" attribute has the same value("file3.java" for example), we list all the relevant classes and methods inside and the same applies for the "Class" attribute, if it has the same name, we list all the methods inside it(So it's like comparing and sorting the values for the "File" and "Class" attributes).
I started with JSON simple library and wrote like the code below, but don't know how to go further!

```
Object object = (JSONArray)parser.parse(new FileReader("rawOutput.json"));            
JSONArray jsonArray =  (JSONArray) object;
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
    String c = jsonObject.get("" + i + "").toString();
}
```

Any ideas? Your help is really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String json = formatJson(new FileReader("rawOutput.json"));
        System.out.println(json);
    }

    public static String formatJson(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        // group array items by fileName
        final Function<List<Map<String, Object>>, Map<String, List<Object>>> groupByFileName =
                data -> data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> (String)map.get("File"), TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())));

        // convert source item structure into required
        final Function<Map.Entry<String, List<Object>>, Map<String, Object>> convert = entry -> {
            Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> tmp = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            entry.getValue().stream()
                    .map(value -> (Map<String, String>)value)
                    .forEach(map -> {
                        Map<String, Map<String, String>> classes = tmp.computeIfAbsent(map.get("Class"), cls -> new TreeMap<>());
                        Map<String, String> methods = classes.computeIfAbsent(map.get("Method"), method -> new TreeMap<>());

                        map.entrySet().stream()
                                .filter(e -> !"Class".equals(e.getKey()) && !"Method".equals(e.getKey()) && !"File".equals(e.getKey()))
                                .forEach(e -> methods.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
                    });

            return Collections.singletonMap(entry.getKey(), tmp);
        };

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // read json as array of Maps
        List<Map<String, Object>> data = Arrays.stream(mapper.readValue(reader, Map[].class))
                .map(map -> map.values().iterator().next())
                .map(item -> (Map<String, Object>)item)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(groupByFileName.apply(data).entrySet().stream()
                .map(convert).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you please point out how can I use your method with my code snippet above? What is the usage for the parameter "String json" in your method above? and what imports did you use?

Comment: See my updated example. I believe, that `new FileReader("rawOutput.json")` returns no exceptions and finds a required file.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Your code works, but it has a bug that if there are more than one method inside the same class, it only lists one method inside the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code to do what do you need but first you have to add this library to your project if you don't have already [org.json.zip library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/org.json/org.json.jar.zip), because I didn't have a library for parsing `Json` texts so I used this library for formatting the `Json` data, and I'm sorry if you don't understand the code completely because your request isn't so easy as yourself know and I created three functions to get the result and although I wrote some comments to understand easily, this is the code:-

> Edit

```
...
import org.json.*;
...
...
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    System.out.println(getFormattedJson("json text"));
}

private static String getFormattedJson(String text) throws JSONException{
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    //get the json array
    jsonArray = new JSONArray(text);

    //loop through items in the array and insert them formatted to the result
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        //get object inside the number
        JSONObject object = getJsonChild(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));

        //get these attributes
        String file = object.getString("File");
        String clas = object.getString("Class");
        String meth = object.getString("Method");
        String anno = object.getString("Annotation");

        //create a custom type of the object's attributes
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Annotation", anno);
        Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put(meth, map);
        Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put(clas, map1);
        Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
        map3.put(file, map2);

        //loop through repeating values to also add them to one value as you expected
        for (int j = jsonArray.length() - 1; j > i; j--) {
            JSONObject obj = getJsonChild(jsonArray.getJSONObject(j));

            String file1 = obj.getString("File");
            String clas1 = obj.getString("Class");
            String meth1 = obj.getString("Method");
            String anno1 = obj.getString("Annotation");

            if (file1.equals(file)) {
                if (map2.containsKey(clas1)) {
                    if (childrenContains(map2, meth1)) {
                        //if the difference was annotation value
                        map.put("Annotation", anno1);
                    } else {
                        //if the difference was method names
                        Map<String, String> map_ = new HashMap<>();
                        map_.put("Annotation", anno1);
                        ((Map<String, Object>) map2.get(clas1)).put(meth1, map_);
                    }
                } else {
                    //if the difference was class names
                    Map<String, String> map_ = new HashMap<>();
                    map_.put("Annotation", anno1);
                    Map<String, Object> map1_ = new HashMap<>();
                    map1_.put(meth1, map_);
                    map2.put(clas1, map1_);
                }

                //remove the (value added) object
                jsonArray.remove(j);
            }
        }

        //add the map to the result
        result.put(map3);
    }

    return  result.toString(4);
}

private static boolean childrenContains(Map<String, Object> map1, String meth1) {
    for (String childKey : map1.keySet()) {
        Map<String, Object> child = (Map<String, Object>) map1.get(childKey);
        if (child.containsKey(meth1))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static JSONObject getJsonChild(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    Iterator<String> keys = object.keys();
    String key = "";
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        key = (String) keys.next();
    }
    return object.getJSONObject(key);
}
```

And the result for your sample using my code is:-

```
[
    {"file1.java": {"com.ETransitionActionType": {"values": {"Annotation": "Not Found"}}}},
    {"file2.java": {"com.ETransitionParams": {"values": {"Annotation": "Not Found"}}}},
    {"file3.java": {
        "com.ExecuteTransitionActionHandler": {
            "createBadRequestResponse": {"Annotation": "Not Found"},
            "extractParametersFromAction": {"Annotation": "Not Found"}
        },
        "com.phloc.commons.id.IHasID": {"getID": {"Annotation": "Not Found"}}
    }}
]
```

---

And if you want to get the `json` data from a file so use the following function to create the `JSONArray` easily:-

```
private static JSONArray readFromFile(String filePath){
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return new JSONArray(sb.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

And use it instead the text `json` data:-

```
...
//get the json array
jsonArray = readFromFile("FilePath");
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am trying out your code, but getting an error saying that readFile method is undefined, should I import something for this method?

Comment: Oh sorry i used a file which includes your json data i forgot to remove it after posting the answer, now i edited the function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It would be great if you provide me with this function that read the json array from a file since I have my json in a file.

Comment: Ok i will show you the `readFile` function, but if the post fixed your problem you can tap on the accept button to know if it was solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a map of maps to represent your grouping by "File" and "Class" for your list of (inner) JSON objects. It might look similar to

```
final Function<JSONObject, String> fileFunction = (JSONObject jsonObject) -> jsonObject.getString("File");
final Function<JSONObject, String> classFunction = (JSONObject jsonObject) -> jsonObject.getString("Class");
final Map<String, Map<String, List<JSONObject>>> groupedJsonObjects = jsonObjects.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(fileFunction, Collectors.groupingBy(classFunction)));
```